# it is possible to send messages from a Java class to Skype for Business distribution group without using client software

Tags: java, api, skype-for-business

it is possible to send messages from a Java class to Skype for Business distribution group without using client software If it is so, then how it is possible.
I am continuously browsing but didn't get any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

We build such a integration and used the XMPP Gateway (but needs to be configured by the system administrator) which is part from a Skype for Business environment. So what we build here, we setup a XMPP Server, our application is working with the XMPP Server and an XMPP Federation between Skype for Business and the XMPP Server. Might be an overkill for your needs but as you didn´t share much more infos about what you wish to build this might be an possible options ;-).